# Nginx support specific wildcard server_name (regex) with fallback

Tags: nginx

Im looking to do the following match:
`*-server.*.*` for example - `dev-server.anydomain.anytld`

in the same file, another server:
`*-cloud.*.*` for example - `dev-cloud.anydomain.anytld`

**fallback** - in the same file - if non of the above were **NOT** matched:
`*.*.*` for example - `dev.anydomain.anytld` or `somethingelse.anydomain.anytld`

This is what I have now which is not working:

```
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  ~(server)*$;
}

server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  ~(cloud)*$;
}

server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  *.*.*$;
}
```

you can use this tool to handle it https://nginx.viraptor.info/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expressions are not valid.

To match `*-server.*.*` use:

```
server_name ~-server\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$;
```

To match `*-cloud.*.*` use:

```
server_name ~-cloud\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$;
```

You do not need a `server_name` statement to match anything else, just use:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

Also, Nginx has a wildcard syntax **and** a regular expression syntax for `server_name` directives. They have different evaluation rules. The above examples use regular expressions, which are evaluated in order until a matching expression is found. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Comment: Hi, the first config answers to both domains: `demo-server.domain.com` and `demo.domain.com`

Comment: It doesn't match the regex so it must be using that `server` block as the `default_server`. Have you defined a `default_server`?

Comment: yes. this `server_name ~-server\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$;` and `default_server`. it always goes to the `server`...